# Scatter plot with colors in order

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, colormap

I have a scatter plot that I'm trying to assign colors to in sequential order. The data is coming from a ton of random files so I can't assign a specific order to the colors to be repeated for all plots.

For this example I was using 'rainbow' color map. I was unable to get a colormap itself assigned to the scatter plot so I used

```
cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow', 17)
for i in range(cmap.N):
    rgb = cmap(i)[:3]
    print(matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(rgb))
```

and it spit out the hex color codes to add to a list.

now my code for the scatter plot is

```
for idx,job in enumerate(job_list):
    colors = ['#8000ff', '#6032fe', '#4062fa', '#208ef4', '#00b4ec', '#20d4e1', '#40ecd4', '#60fac5', '#80ffb4', '#9ffaa2', '#bfec8e', '#dfd478', '#ffb462', '#ff8e4a', '#ff6232', '#ff3219', '#ff0000']
    x = temp
    y = slope
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=colors[idx])
plt.show()
```

and I get this with the colors all out of order
[image]

so overall my question is how can I get my scatter plot to have colors from a colormap (I want to use coolwarm but rainbow was easier to visualize) in order, whether it be using hex or somehow a color map with a scatter plot.

Thanks so much for your time and any advice you may have!

Comment: `plt.scatter` accepts both a color parameter, `c` (which can be a single value or an iterable of values with a length equal to `y` and `x`), and a `cmap` parameter. Using both will color your points using the `c` values. In your case if you want to color the points in order do something like `plt.scatter(x, y, c=x, cmap=“rainbow”)`.

Comment: @DavidHoffman, I got that but using `c=x` it gives me `'c' argument has 9 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 1.` with any other value it will give me my plot but all just the same dark blue I assume from `cmap=rainbow` somewhere. Do you have any further insight? Thank you either way!

Comment: Could you clarify your code (as written it doesn’t make sense): where do `temp` and `slope` come from? What are `job` and `job_list`?